# How to add white spaces in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the following lines in my haml file.

```
(Requested:
                            %strong<>
                              = comment.commentable.requested_check_in.present? ? comment.commentable.requested_check_in.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : ""
                              ="-"
                              = comment.commentable.requested_check_out.present? ? comment.commentable.requested_check_out.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : ""
                            , Actual:
                            %strong<>
                              = comment.commentable.actual_check_in.present? ? comment.commentable.actual_check_in.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : ""
                              ="-"
                              = comment.commentable.actual_check_out.present? ? comment.commentable.actual_check_out.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : ""
                            ).
```

what i want is that to have a white space after

```
(Requested: " "
```

but this line is not working.

Comment: How does the generated HTML look like and what is your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

after being going through different platforms i finally found solutions see the code.

```
(Requested:&nbsp
                            %strong<>
                              = comment.commentable.requested_check_in.present? ? comment.commentable.requested_check_in.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : ""
                              &nbsp-&nbsp
                              = comment.commentable.requested_check_out.present? ? comment.commentable.requested_check_out.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : ""
                            , Actual:&nbsp
                            %strong<>
                              = comment.commentable.actual_check_in.present? ? comment.commentable.actual_check_in.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : ""
                              &nbsp-&nbsp
                              = comment.commentable.actual_check_out.present? ? comment.commentable.actual_check_out.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : ""
                            ).
```

you can use shortcode (&nbsp) whereever you want space in haml

Comment: This is a hack. It's not the "right" way to do it. Hang on, I'll give you a proper answer in a minute...

Comment: @TomLord longest minute I've ever heard of.

Comment: @jugglervr I posted an answer above, 3 years ago! (But OK it did take me 30 minutes, not 1.)

Answer (score 1):

[`&nbsp` stands for **non-breaking space**](http://yesterdayishere.com/now/what-nbsp-means-and-does/).

Normally, HTML will truncate spaces in your text. If you write 10 spaces, only 1 will be displayed. `&nbsp` is one way to *force* additional spaces to appear, but it is rarely the "right" way to do it.

A valid use case might be: `Mr.&nbspUsman` -to force the two words to appear together on the same line.

All you need to do here is wrap the text in quotes:

```
= '(Requested: '
%strong= comment.commentable.requested_check_in&.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
- if comment.commentable.requested_check_out
  = ' - '
  %strong= comment.commentable.requested_check_out.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
= ')'
= '(Actual: '
%strong= comment.commentable.actual_check_in&.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
- if comment.commentable.actual_check_out
  = ' - '
  %strong= comment.commentable.actual_check_out.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
= ')'
```

This code is very messy, however. It is not advisable to put such complex logic in a view. I would advise moving this logic out into a helper method; perhaps consider using the [`draper`](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) library? Your refactored view code could end up looking something like this:

```
!= "(Requested: <strong>#{comment.commentable.requested_check_out_range}</strong>)"
!= "(Actual: <strong>#{comment.commentable.actual_check_out_range}</strong>)"
```

...With the conditional logic moved into `./app/decorators/*.rb`.

If you did need to format the text with *multiple*, non-truncated white-space then you should typically instead use the [`white-space` CSS property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a blank space on HAML, use the following cheatcode:

```
  = parseFloat(elem.value) > 1.00 ? 'X' : "\n\b"
```

Hope it would be useful.